# Rotating the findspeaks function from columns to rows

Tags: matlab

I have a small function that finds the peaks in a matrix and then replacing it by 0. The end output is related to the columns. I'm having hard time fixing the syntax to make it work the same way but for the rows as well. Any ideas ? Here's the code :

```
HVAzimuthFreqAbs = abs(HVAzimuthFreq);
M = HVAzimuthFreqAbs;
for k1 = 1:size(M,1)
[pks,loc] = findpeaks(M(k1,:),'Threshold',150);
P{k1} = [pks; loc];
end
HVAzimuthFreq(:,loc) = 0;
```

The main key as I understand is to switch between the order that the size refers to, but I have no luck in doing that. For example -

```
for k1 = 1:size(1,M)
[pks,loc] = findpeaks(M(:,K1),'Threshold',ThresholdUpper);
P{k1} = [pks; loc];
end
```

is giving me an 'Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range' error.

Any ideas ?
thanks

Comment: Swap the dimensions around? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm a novice in Matlab, How do I swap the dimensions ? everything that I try results in an error

Comment: Show your attempts. Edit them into the question. Do **not** do it in the comments. Explain what goes wrong with each, in detail. Right now this looks like a request for free code, which is off topic here.

Comment: does `findpeaks(M(:,K1).','Threshold',ThresholdUpper);` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at the `for` line, `size(1,M)` makes no sense. Use `size(M,2)` to get the number of columns.

You are indexing the columns as `M(:,K1)`, this is correct.